# Reduce the output layer size from XLTransformers

Tags: huggingface-transformers

I'm running the following using the huggingface implementation:

```
t1 = "My example sentence is really great."

tokenizer = TransfoXLTokenizer.from_pretrained('transfo-xl-wt103')
model = TransfoXLLMHeadModel.from_pretrained("transfo-xl-wt103")

encoded_input = tokenizer(t1, return_tensors='pt', add_space_before_punct_symbol=True) 
output = model(**encoded_input)
tmp = output[0].detach().numpy()
print(tmp.shape)

>>> (1, 7, 267735)
```

With the goal of getting output embeddings that I'll use downstream.

The last dimension is /substantially/ larger than I expected, and it looks like it is the size of the entire `vocab_size` rather than a reduction based on the [ECL from the paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1901.02860.pdf.) (which potentially I am misinterpreting).

What argument would I provide the `model` to reduce this layer size to a smaller dimensional space, something more like the basic BERT at 400 or 768 and still obtain good performance based on the pretrained embeddings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you used `...LMHeadModel`, which predicts the next token. You can use `TransfoXLModel.from_pretrained("transfo-xl-wt103")` instead, then `output[0]` is the last hidden state which has the shape `(batch_size, sequence_length, hidden_size)`.